# Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Observable<SearchResult[]>' Angular 5 using HttpClient instead of Http

Tags: angular, observable

I'm trying to use the new HttpClient class instead of the old Http.

I want to map over the data I get from the subscribe method, but get the below error. Any suggestions on why I get this?

Code:

```
export class YoutubeSearchService {
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    @Inject(YOUTUBE_API_KEY) private apiKey: string,
    @Inject(YOUTUBE_API_URL) private apiUrl: string,
  ) { }

  search(query: string): Observable<SearchResult[]> {
    const params: string = [
      `q=${query}`,
      `key=${this.apiKey}`,
      `part=snippet`,
      `type=video`,
      `maxResults=10`,
    ].join("&");
    const queryUrl = `${this.apiUrl}?${params}`;
    return this.http.get(queryUrl).subscribe(data => {
      data.map(item => {
        return new SearchResult({
          id: item.id.videoId,
          title: item.snippet.title,
          description: item.snippet.description,
          thumbnailUrl: item.snippet.thumbnails.high.url,
        });
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Error:

```
ERROR in src/app/services/youtube-search.service.ts(26,5): error TS2322: Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Observable<SearchResult[]>'.
  Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'Subscription'.
src/app/services/youtube-search.service.ts(27,12): error TS2339: Property 'map' doesnot exist on type 'Object'.
```

Answer (score 12):

Your `search` method is returning a `subscription` but the signature claims it should return an `Observable<SearchResult[]>`

To fix this either change the signature of your method or change the `subscribe` to `map`

Comment: I can't do map with httpClient. Or? Read https://blog.angular.io/version-5-0-0-of-angular-now-available-37e414935ced under HttpClient

Comment: You have to remove the map to `json` because the new `HttpClient` created a json object for you. So you can perfectly use a `map` if you want to change the returned object, or just remove it.

Comment: I get Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'.

Comment: `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'`

Comment: Hi @Venomy, Fixed it: https://jsfiddle.net/2w8xsqdo/2/ now this error:  file: 'file:///Users/isaklafleur/Google%20Drive/Isak/Coding/angular-youtube-search/src/app/services/youtube-search.service.ts'
severity: 'Error'
message: 'Type 'Observable<SearchResult>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<SearchResult[]>'.
  Type 'SearchResult' is not assignable to type 'SearchResult[]'.
    Property 'includes' is missing in type 'SearchResult'.'
at: '28,5'
source: 'ts'
code: '2322'

Comment: Can you try using this:`return this.http.get<SearchResult[]>(queryUrl)`

Answer (score 0):

To return the Observable, use:

```
return this.http.get(queryUrl);
```

and do the subscription on the calling end. 
If you need to map your return object from the Http call to a different object. Then one solution would be to define a subject and inside your subscription, you perform a next operation on this subject.

As for the second error, you are getting for using map function. You can use 
return this.http.get(queryUrl);
to make the compiler view it as a an array instead of a single object. I am not sure that this what you wanted to achieve or not.

Answer (score 0):

easily , you don't use for return value.

```
.valueChanges()
```