# TSLint errors in Angular2 project: Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'FirebaseListObservable<any[]>'

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, eslint, tslint

Having this issue, can't figure it out...

Here's the relevant code:

```
export class AdminComponent {
  items: FirebaseListObservable < any[] > ;
  private xyz: string;
  private fbList: FirebaseListObservable < any[] > ;
  private userData: object[];
  private userEid: object[];
  private userFullName: object[];
  private uniqueID: string;
  private quizAnswerA: string;

  private userList = [];
  private userAnswer1: any;

  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase, private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.fbList = db.list('/');

    this.items = this.fbList.map(items => {
      const dbAnalytics = items[0];
      const dbBookings = items[1];
      const dbClasses = items[2];
      const dbLabs = items[3];
      const dbMachines = items[4];
      const dbPostLabs = items[5];
      const dbPreLabs = items[6];
      const dbUsers = items[7];

      for (const key of Object.keys(dbUsers)) {
        if (dbUsers.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          this.userData = dbUsers[key];
          this.uniqueID = key;
          this.userEid = this.userData['eid'] !== undefined ? this.userData['eid'] : 'N/A';
          this.userFullName = this.userData['name'];

        }
        let time = 'N/A';
        let count = 0;
        let runs = dbAnalytics['expRuns'];
        if ((key in runs)) {
          let experiments = runs[key]['-KVQN-Qk-CLh_KupgKTt'];
          count = Object.keys(experiments)
            .length;
          try {
            time = experiments[Object.keys(experiments)[Object.keys(experiments)
              .length - 1]]['time'].replace('T', '  ')
              .split('.')[0];
          } catch (e) {}

        }

        let firstQuizAnswer = dbPostLabs['-KVQN-Qk-CLh_KupgKTt']['a']['completed'];
        let secondQuizAnswer = dbPostLabs['-KVQN-Qk-CLh_KupgKTt']['b']['completed'];
        let thirdQuizAnswer = dbPostLabs['-KVQN-Qk-CLh_KupgKTt']['c']['completed'];
        let fourthQuizAnswer = dbPostLabs['-KVQN-Qk-CLh_KupgKTt']['d']['completed'];

        let store = new Row(this.userFullName, this.userEid, this.uniqueID, count, time, firstQuizAnswer[key], secondQuizAnswer[key], thirdQuizAnswer[key], fourthQuizAnswer[key]);
        this.userList.push(store);
      }
    }
    );
  }

}
```

Errors:

> TS2322: Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'FirebaseListObservable'.   Property '$ref' is missing in type 'Subscription'.

How can I fix these? I'm new to both firebase and angular2. All suggestions are appreciated.

I tried using this (similar) question, but to no avail.

[Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Observable<SearchResult[]>' Angular 5 using HttpClient instead of Http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47220907/type-subscription-is-not-assignable-to-type-observablesearchresult-angul?rq=1)

Thanks!

Comment: Does adding `.valueChanges()` to the `db.list(..)` help?

Comment: @Phix Unfortunately, that gives me a new error: `TS2339: Property 'valueChanges' does not exist on type 'FirebaseListObservable<any[]>'.`

Comment: I'm sure you have already, but I'd go over the [examples in the docs](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md) one more time :)

Comment: @Phix yes, I've gone over the examples in the docs. Still unclear about how to approach this.

Comment: I made a very small [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rt-database), feel free to fork and update to see if we can get closer.

Comment: so is db.list returning an Observable that you can subscribe to?

Comment: @PariBaker afaik, yes, but i'm so new to angular2 that i don't really know.

Comment: Check out my answer alternatively to get to the next error in your code, just add .ValueChanges and change fbList to a regular Observable

Comment: That will bring you to the next error which is using .map on an observable... you need to first call .pipe() then import map from rxjs/operators (angular 6) and add the map .pipe(map())

Answer (score 0):

So following your stackBlitz I believe I have found your issue, without knowing what the data will look like at the end I can tell you what is going on. First of all I suggest separating your logic as in the stackBlitz example, with a service.

Whether you do or don't first of all make fbList into an Observable not a FireBaseObservableList - I believe it is deprecated anyway. I also made items as an empty array of type any too (again I don't know what you want the end result to look like) but in anycase I didn't use the angular | async pipe) and add the .ValueChanges() to the fbList to make it an Observable.

Alternatively if you know what your data will look like and want to use map then you do can declare items as a type of it then if you want to use the map operator, first import it to angular from rxjs/operators and remember you must use .pipe(map()) first. Check out the example and try it without doing all the other stuff first to see it works. If you need more direction on the model please update a sample of the data.

https://angular-rt-database-dmw7gd.stackblitz.io